# $.getJSON function with json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've the below combination of server-side and client-side json processing code. I'm able to load json data from `remote url` and from local `.js` file. 
But, somehow I'm unable to figure out how to load data from the `serverjson` object in the below code snippet.

```
    var json ;     

    <#list jsons as json>
             serverjson = ${json};
             console.log(serverjson);


          $.getJSON(---have to load data from json object----).done(function (jsonData) {
            var time = 0; var curc = 0; var prec = 0;
            $.each(jsonData.current.timeSeries, function(i,item){
                //console.log(jsonData.current.timeSeries[i].beginTimeSeconds+" : "+jsonData.current.timeSeries[i].endTimeSeconds+" : "+jsonData.current.timeSeries[i].inspectedCount);
                time = jsonData.current.timeSeries[i].beginTimeSeconds;
                curc = jsonData.current.timeSeries[i].inspectedCount;
                //curdata.addRows([curc]);
                curdata.push(curc)
                //data.addRows([[jsonData.current.timeSeries[i].beginTimeSeconds,jsonData.current.timeSeries[i].endTimeSeconds,jsonData.current.timeSeries[i].inspectedCount]]);

           });
</#list>
```

So, to conclude, I'm not passing `remote url` or `.js` file in the `$.getJSON()` function, I need to pass `serverjson` object.

Please help me how to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$.getJSON(---have to load data from json object----).done(function (jsonData) {
     // code
});
```

do:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(serverjson);
// code
```

Comment: Thanks, The question is a stupid one. Now I realized. In fact after posting I got this idea. I just need to copy serverjson objec to jsonData. That's all.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, it depends whether *serverjson* is really JSON, or already a JavaScript object. If it is the first, you need `JSON.parse`, if it is the second, no conversion is needed. But one advise: don't call variables `jsonData` or `serverjson` if they are not strings, because then they are not JSON. JSON is a text format. JavaScript objects are not text.